# CAD software for Meccano models building and simulation

Tags: cad

I have just started with Meccano multi-model kit for learning about machines. I want to know if there is any CAD software available for  designing and simulating these models on computer?
I will prefer windows based software.

Comment: Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information and [edit] your question. OS, price. link to the *Meccano multi-model kit*, etc.